# Product of elements in Finite ring

Tags: ring-theory, finite-rings

Let $R$ be a finite ring with or without unity. Can one give a short description of the product of all elements of $R^{\times}$?

Here, we denote by $R^{\times}$ the set of all nonzero elements of $R$, not (as usual) the set of all invertible elements of $R$.

Comment: There isn't necessarily a multiplicative subgroup of a ring, because there aren't always multiplicative inverses.

Comment: edited again I am meaning all elements without $0$.

Comment: Still, what kind of a description are you looking for? This is a vague question at best.

Comment: Turns out to be a question with a very interesting answer. +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To summarize some of the comments, thanks to peoplepower for completing the solution.

We have three situations:

**Case 1:** The ring is an integral domain. Then it is a field. Let $n=p^k$ be the number of elements.

Then $R^*$ is a cyclic group. Let $a$ be a generator. Then you product is

$$P=a\cdot a^2 \cdot...\cdot a^{n-1}=a^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$$

If $p=2$ then since $a^{n-1}=1$ the product is one. Otherwise, $n-1 \nmid \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ thus $P\neq 1$ and $P^2=1$. This means $P=-1$.

For domains, the product is always $-1$.

**Case 2:** The ring contains at least two zero divisors. If any of the zero divisors has the property that $x^2 \neq 0$, we are done, because the definition of zero divisors guarantees then that the product is zero.

Otherwise, let $x,y$ be two distinct zero divisors. Then we know that $xx=yy=0$.

This shows that $x(xy)=0$ and $(xy)y=0$.

If $xy=0$, we are done, if $xy=x\neq y$ then $(xy)y=0$; otherwise $x(xy)=0$ is the product of non-zero distinct elements.

**Case 3:** The ring contains exactly one zero divisor $x$. Let $R^X=\{ y_1,..,y_k,x \}$. Then since $y_1,..,y_k$ are not zero divisors we have 
$y_1..y_kx \neq 0$. But this is a zero divisor, thus

$$y_1..y_kx=x \,.$$

In this case, the product is the unique zero divisor.

Comment: Subcase 3.b: Suppose $R$ is commutative with unity.  Then by the classification of (commutative, unital) Artinian rings, $R$ is the direct product of local rings.  But the product of 2 or more nonzero rings will not have the property in 3.b: (1,0) is a zero divisor but its square is not zero.  Thus $R$ must be a local ring.  In a finite local ring, the zero divisors = the maximal ideal.  Now what?

Comment: In 3.b we have that such a zero divisor is unique via a proof by contradiction: say $x\ne y$ satisfy those two properties, then $xy\ne 0$ and yet $xyy=0$ so $xy=y$ and $xxy=0$, whence $x=xy=y$. Let x be the zero divisor. Now, every nonzero element y of R satisfies $0=(x+x)y=xy+xy=x(y+y)$; then $y=-y$ or $y=x-y$.

Comment: Ty, added it and then cleaned the solution.

Comment: It is surprising that we need to consider only three cases and that the most unnatural instances have a uniform, simple answer (esp. across the divide of commutativity/noncommutativity). My primary interest was to break it by having too many elements commute, but all that is unnecessary and you found a nice way to get to the answer. +1

Comment: I'm not getting it. Isn't $R^{\times}$, by definition, the group of invertible elements, not the monoid of nonzero elements, of $R$ ?

Comment: Also, I'm not seeing what you are doing in Case 2. Are you requiring $xy=0$ ?

Comment: @darijgrinberg That is the point, you don't know what $xy$ is. If $xy=0$ you are done. If it is not zero, it could be $x$, $y$ or something else. But it cannot be both $x$ and $y$. So basically you have 3 cases: $xy=0$, $xy=x$ and $xy$ is neither.

Comment: @darijgrinberg As for your other question, read the Question including the OPs comment under the question ;)

Comment: Ah. I've queued an edit of the OP, since notations should be defined unless they are used in their standard meaning. About $xy$, what do you do in the "$xy$ is neither" case?

Comment: @darijgrinberg I edited that case to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

$0$. Since $0$ is an element, it is in the product of all elements (this is true since a ring $R$ is an abelian group under $+$, so has an additive identity).

EDIT: I agree with DoctorBatmanGod that rings are generally very complicated objects. If we're talking about a ring that isn't an integral domain, then the result may or may not be $0$, for example, $\Bbb Z_4$ and $\Bbb Z_6$, respectively. Even if we restrict ourselves to the units in an arbitrary ring, then we might end up with an empty product since we can choose a ring that is comprised of zero divisors. On the other hand, if we *are* talking about integral domains, then it is possibly easier as then it is a field. However, that need not get us out of the woods, so to speak. In a boolean ring, every element is its own multiplicative inverse and additive inverse, hence the product of all of the nonzero elements will precisely be $x_1\cdots x_n$. Thus, there isn't any reduction we can do aside from calculate the entire product.

End result: I'd say that there isn't a general method that applies to all rings, even when they're finite. There are too many additional structures on the algebra portion that affect what you want.

Comment: I will change the question

Comment: What kind of a description are you looking for? There may be many subgroups closed with respect to multiplication, or there may not be any since a ring doesn't necessarily have multiplicative inverses. If the ring doesn't have unity, then in this case, there wouldn't even be a trivial multiplicative subgroup.

Comment: Example: In $\mathbb{Z}_{4}$, $1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 = 2$. Can we find what element should it be without going through all the multiplications?

Comment: Not necessarily. For example, in $\Bbb Z_6$, we have $1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 5=0$, while in any boolean ring, we'd have $x_1x_2\cdots x_n$, assuming there are $n$ elements. Basically, even excluding zero, you can still have zero divisors. If you specify only the product of units, then it may be empty since there aren't necessarily units.

Comment: @Arul: I've edited my answer. Also take a look at N.S. and DonAntonio's solutions. You may find them helpful.

Answer (score 1):

For commutative rings:

1) If $\,R\,$ has non-zero divisors of zero then the product's obviously zero **unless** all of the zero divisors are nilpotent, which can occur only with $\,\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z\,$ (why?) , and in this case the product equals $\,2\,$=the non-zero nilpotent element.

2) If $\,R\,$ is an integral domain then it is a field (why? This is a nice exercise), and thus the set of all its non-zero elements is a multiplicative group.

i) First subcase: $\,|R|=p^n\,\,,\,p\,$ an odd prime. Since there exists only one element of order 2 here (why?), namely $\,-1\,$ , the wanted product is precisely $\,-1\,$ (why?)

ii) Second subcase: $\,|R|=2^n\,$ . Since here all the non-zero elements have odd multiplicative order, the result is $\,1\,$

Answer (score 0):

An arbitrary finite ring in an incredibly complicated object. If the ring isn't an integral domain then the answer is $0$. Otherwise the simplest representation would probably be exactly as you put the question, $\prod_{r \in R}r$. Even with groups, which are "easier" to manipulate, finding what a product is given elements and rules governing products of those elements can get really tricky.

Comment: When can we say something useful?

Comment: Even if the ring isn't an integral domain, the product of all nonzero elements might not be 0: In $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ the product 1*2*3=2.  (This is the only counterexample among rings $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ though)

Comment: @Arul: That is an entirely different question, and seemingly subjective. What is considered "useful" to you?

Comment: @Ted: We dont want $0$. It is uninteresting. I just want to know is there anyway to say what the final product would be without multiplying all the elements.

Comment: @Clayton Fix a ordering of the elements. If I can predict the final product within $O(log(|R^{\times}|))$ of the exact location in the order, that will be useful.

Comment: @N.S. I meant "even if the ring *isn't* an integral domain" (corrected now)